# Querying wpdb using PHP

Tags: php, wpdb, sql

I'm a beginner trying to query a table in my wordpress database and would appreciate some pointers on where I'm going wrong... I've got a table of cricket statistics, and want to get the highest score from a column.

The code is below, and when I include `$wpdb->show_errors();`, I get: *WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1]*

The data type of the Runs_1 column is *int*

```
<?php
$top_score = $wpdb->get_var (" SELECT MAX(Runs_1) FROM $wpdb->Bangalore") ;
echo "<p>Top first innings score is {$top_score} </p>";
?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is the table name `Bangalore`? `wp_ Bangalore`? Or something else?

Comment: It's called Bangalore. I've just been tinkering with it, and it didn't need the $wpdb-> before it. Thanks, though.